# custom summerType in xtraGrid gridControl

Tags: c#, gridview, xtragrid, devexpress-windows-ui, group-summaries

How can add a custom summerType in xtraGrid gridControl?

I would like to add a `SummerItem` to a column in my `xtraGrid gridControl` named `total percent` whitch will calculate the percentage of the two other columns.

In total I have 3 columns 
1. Quantities of Items A 
2. Total Quantities and
3. Percentage

Also I have `summaryItems` with

```
1. Sum of column 1 (`Quantities of Item A`)
2. Sum of column 2 (`Total Quantities`) and 
3. Total Percentage whitch I would like to make a divition with ( column 1 / column 2 ) * 100
```

My question is how can I do this? I should use a `Custom Summary Type` ? if yes how can use this type?

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here 
https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_CustomSummaryCalculatetopic

Works perfect for me

I create two private variables in my class

```
private decimal _sumOfValues = 0;
private decimal _sumOfTotalValue = 0;
```

Created a `custom summary type` in the percentage column and in option `Tag` typed `percentageColumnCustomSummary` whitch is the ID of this summary column

Create an event on my xtraGrid

```
private void allocationGridView_CustomSummaryCalculate(object sender, DevExpress.Data.CustomSummaryEventArgs e)
```

And typed bellow code

```
private void allocationGridView_CustomSummaryCalculate(object sender, DevExpress.Data.CustomSummaryEventArgs e) 
        {
            try
            {
                //int summaryID = Convert.ToInt32((e.Item as GridSummaryItem).Tag);
                string summaryTag = Convert.ToString((e.Item as GridSummaryItem).Tag);
                GridView View = sender as GridView;

                // Initialization 
                if (e.SummaryProcess == CustomSummaryProcess.Start) {

                    _sumOfValues = 0;
                    _sumOfTotalValue = 0;
                }

                //Calculate
                if (e.SummaryProcess == CustomSummaryProcess.Calculate) {

                    decimal colValueColumnValue = Convert.ToDecimal( View.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, "Value") );
                    decimal colTotalValueColumnValue = Convert.ToDecimal( View.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, "TotalValue") );

                    switch (summaryTag) {
                        case "percentageColumnCustomSummary":
                            _sumOfValues += colValueColumnValue;
                            _sumOfTotalValue += colTotalValueColumnValue;
                            break;
                    }
                }

                // Finalization 
                if (e.SummaryProcess == CustomSummaryProcess.Finalize) {
                    switch (summaryTag) {
                        case "percentageColumnCustomSummary":
                            e.TotalValue = 0;
                            if (_sumOfTotalValue != 0) {
                                e.TotalValue = (_sumOfValues / _sumOfTotalValue);
                            }

                            break;
                    }
                }  
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.ErrorException("allocationGridView_CustomSummaryCalculate", ex);
            }

        }
```

This works great!